# Importing same name file from different directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a directory structure like -

- D

  - dir1

    - filetoimport.py
  - dir2

    - filetoimport.py
    - run.py

Filetoimport.py code-

```
call_function()
    do_something
    return
```

Run.py has -

```
import filetoimport
filetoimport.call_function()
```

the dir2 is essentially a copy of dir1 with some changes but run.py is still calling filetoimport from dir1. I don't get what am I missing here?

EDIT 1- dir1 and dir2 are not packages but just plain directories.

Comment: And you added the local `__init__.py`?

Comment: It is not recommanded to call modules with the same name. Have you put an `__init__. py` file in each package? Finaly you should call it from the root. `from dir2 import filetoimport`

Comment: Use correct folder structure and **make sure you're in correct working directory**! | As for colliding names, with correct folder structure you can do `from package.module import needed_function`, or `import package.module` (qualified name with package name), or `import package.module as different_name` (you can do `as` on single functions with colliding names as well!)

Comment: @FlorianBernard getting no module named dir2 error

Comment: @user2828360 `from D.dir2 import filetoimport`. And you should have init file in each directory.

Comment: @FlorianBernard no module named D.dir2

Comment: @user2828360 so you folder is not in the python Path.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are running your code from *dir1* as the working directory (you can check with `os.get_cwd()`).
Change your working directory to dir2 and it should import the filetoimport.py under dir2.

If you want to be sure what was imported you can `print(fileimport.__file__)`

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. print(os.getcwd()) shows the correct directory

Comment: your working directory is dir2? what fileimport.__file__ shows?
Are u running it from simple shell or from ide?

Comment: if you print sys.path, do you see dir1 there?
did you set the PYTHONPATH environment variable?